# Dynamic list-view population (three lists, one per page - all in same HTML)

Tags: jquery, ajax, listview, jquery-mobile

I have a single HTML page where I need to have three jqm `pages` (data-role=page) (named `#one`, `#two`, `#three`).  In each but page `#one`, I also have a back button in the header.  In each page, I have a simple `listview`.  On HTML generation, only the `listview` on page `#one` is populated.  On click of an item in the list, I perform some ajax to get the contents of the next list and populate it.  Everything works great until I click the back button and select a different item from the list.  The result is that the nicely formatted jqm `listview` becomes a vertical list of links, not jqm styled and colored horiz bars with content.

My HTML and script is below.

```
<div data-role="page" id="one">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Make</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="b" id="cutpoint_makes_mobile">
            @foreach (var make in Model)
            {
                <li><a href="#">@make</a></li>
            }
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="two">
    <div data-role="header">
        <a href="#one" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-l">Back</a>
        <h1>Model</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="b" id="cutpoint_models_mobile">
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="three">
    <div data-role="header">
        <a href="#two" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-l">Back</a>
        <h1>Size</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="b" id="cutpoint_sizes_mobile">
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="four">
    <div data-role="header">
        <a href="#three" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-l">Back</a>
        <h1>Details</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <h2 id="cutpoint_detail_mobile">
        </h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

... and the jquery code ...

```
var make = null;
var model = null;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#cutpoint_makes_mobile a").click(function () {
        make = $(this).text();
        loadAllModelsMobile_Request(make);
    });
    $("#cutpoint_models_mobile a").live("click", function () {
        model = $(this).text();
        loadAllSizesMobile_Request(make, model);
    });
    $("#cutpoint_sizes_mobile a").live("click", function () {
        var size = $(this).text();
        loadDetailsMobile_Request(make, model, size);
    });
});

// NOTE, only the load models ajax calls are listed for brevity
// *** loadAllModelsMobile (Request/Response/Error) ***
function loadAllModelsMobile_Request(make) {
    var qs = "make=" + make;
    var url = "/HomeJson/CutPointsAllModels";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        dataType: "json",
        data: qs,
        success: loadAllModelsMobile_Response,
        error: loadAllModelsMobile_Error
    });
}
function loadAllModelsMobile_Response(data) {
    if (data.Success) {
        $("#cutpoint_models_mobile").find("li").remove().end();
        model = null;
        $.each(data.Data, function () {
            $("#cutpoint_models_mobile").append('<li><a href="#">' + this + '</a></li>');
        });
        $.mobile.changePage($("#two"));
    } else {
        // ToDo: handle errors
        //$("#admin_alert_msg").text(data.Data);
        //$("#dlg_admin_alert").dialog("open");
    }
}
function loadAllModelsMobile_Error(xhr) {
    // ToDo: handle errors
    //showAjaxErrorMessage("loadAllModelsMobile_Error", xhr.status, xhr.response);
}
```

I even used the `pagebeforechange` event notification and cleared out the `li` in there, but no change (same as clearing out the `li` in the ajax response since that's before page change).

**My question**: how do I get jqm to style the list after it has already been styled once and I remove/replace its contents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some notes; this line does not need the `.end()` function call, that is used to return to the previous selection and you aren't doing anything with the selection:

```
$("#cutpoint_models_mobile").find("li").remove().end();
```

Should change to:

```
$("#cutpoint_models_mobile").find("li").remove();
```

Appending each LI is CPU expensive, a better alternative is to either concoct a string or create an array of LIs.

Change:

```
    $.each(data.Data, function () {
        $("#cutpoint_models_mobile").append('<li><a href="#">' + this + '</a></li>');
    });
```

To:

```
    var output = [];
    for (var i = 0, len = data.Data.length; i < len; i++) {
        output[output.length] = '<li><a href="#">' + data.Data[i] + '</a></li>';
    }
    $("#cutpoint_models_mobile").append(output.join(''));
```

The `for` loop I used also performs faster than `$.each()` (although `$.each()` is quite a bit faster than `$(<selector>)).each()` and `for (a in b)`).

## Now to get to your question.

You have to manually refresh `listview` widgets (and all other widgets) if you update their structure. You can do this with the `.listview()` function by passing it the string: "refresh". So the example just above this would turn-out like this:

```
    var output = [];
    for (var i = 0, len = data.Data.length; i < len; i++) {
        output[output.length] = '<li><a href="#">' + data.Data[i] + '</a></li>';
    }
    $("#cutpoint_models_mobile").append(output.join('')).listview('refresh');
```

Documentation for `listview` widgets is here: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/lists/docs-lists.html (the section regarding updating a `listview` is at the bottom of the page)

**UPDATE**

Sometimes you will run into the problem of not knowing if the `listview` has been initialized yet or not. You can check for the existence of the `.ui-listview` class on the `<ul>` element, if it is there then the `listview` has already been initialized:

```
    var output    = [],
        $listview = $("#cutpoint_models_mobile");
    for (var i = 0, len = data.Data.length; i < len; i++) {
        output[output.length] = '<li><a href="#">' + data.Data[i] + '</a></li>';
    }

    $listview.append(output.join(''))
    if ($listview.hasClass('ui-listview')) {
        $listview.listview('refresh');
    } else {
        $listview.trigger('create');
    }
```

Comment: That all makes perfect sense.  I'm now getting the following exception.  How do I initialize it first before calling the refresh?  uncaught exception: cannot call methods on listview prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'

Comment: @Ed.S. I updated my answer. Basically you can't refresh a non-initialized widget, but you can initialize it.

Comment: thanks for the update. Unfortunately, I now get an error in the bowels of jqm.js.  "parentPage[0] is undefined" on line 4378 of jquery.mobile-1.0.js.  It's happening when I call the listview() method with no args.  Looking into this solution now... http://forum.jquery.com/topic/parentpage-0-is-undefined#14737000002707452

Comment: @Ed.S. Try using `.trigger('create')` instead of `.listview()`. I normally use `.trigger('create')`, not sure why I used the other method in the answer.

Comment: Great.  Working.  Thank you very much!

Comment: I was too late, but here is a jsfiddle I made a while ago that shows when the `listview` is initialized or refreshed: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/urTeW/1/